How to easily find all executables linked against certain libc6 version?
Background
It is an Ubuntu-based OS, where I manually built & installed Arch's pacman, added Arch's repositories to it, and ran pacman --force -S git to test it out. It was a mistake, yes. git had libc6 and some coreutils as dependencies. Pacman satisfied them, overwriting my current (Ubuntu's) ones. The "installation" didn't even finish because some essential tools (like cat I guess) stopped working — libc6 was shifted to a different (newer) version, incompatible with other binaries. I forcely rebooted. Systemd doesn't start up properly now. I mounted the root drive in a different setup, and changed the libc6 to Ubuntu's one. But even then it didn't work because some (actually, quite a lot) of the binaries (including sh) were actually updated by pacman, and they now want a newer libc6, while others (which are still old) do not.
I mounted the root drive in a different system again.
Problem
As I understand, dynamicly linked binaries which need libc6 are linked against a specific version — that's why I have issues. What is the simplest way to automatically find all the binaries in the filesystem, which are linked against a specific libc6 version? I will then be able to reinstall the corresponding packages using chroot /mydrive busybox sh and dpkg which is statically linked.
Thanks for any help!

Is it worth the effort? Reinstalling would be simpler and cleaner

The ldd command will extract the shared library dependencies from an executable.  However, I agree it would be simpler and probably faster to just reinstall.

@user10489 thanks I'll have a look at ldd (I always thought that it can't show versions). I don't really want to reinstall because it is a highly manual setup, with lots of packages manually installed. I already manage most things outside of package managers, so I'll care about the "clean" thing. Anyway, do you think that fully replacing all core binaries with pacman-provided ones is also way, instead of returning to Ubuntu's?

Does Arch use multiarch (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu) or multilib paths? If the latter, you might be able to fix things by configuring the dynamic loader to look in the path with the newer libc.

That's a good point.  You should be able to install both versions of libc, possibly in different directories.  If you're lucky, ldconfig/ld.so might be able to figure out which one to use; if not, you'd have to edit each executable and set the internal library run path correctly.

@user10489 that shouldn’t be necessary, since glibc is backwards-compatible — as long as ld.so finds the newer one, everything should work. I suspect that for whatever reason the newer Arch binaries are being loaded with the older Ubuntu libc...

@StephenKitt yes, it turned out I was using the old libc6. I copied (without deleting) /lib and /lib64 with cp -af from an Arch Linux "bootstrap" image. Now I can boot from that filesystem, and even log in, I don't know yet if something else is broken. Thanks for your help!
